# How to properly implement AsyncTask in android?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

During Implementing AsyncTask I have set setCancelable(true) in the progressDialog.But what it does is whenever user clicks on the screen or presses 'Back' button while loading,the dialog box disappears and no data is shown on that activity.I have to again press 'Back' to get back to the previous activity.
If I set setCancelable(false) then user's clicking on the screen has no effect but then 'Back' Button also does not work.I want to implement this- Clicking on the screen should produce no effect and pressing 'back' button in between should take user back to previous acivity.Such situation arrives when internet is too slow and dialog takes too much time on the screen.
Also I have tried to set connectiontimeout in my JSONParserclass and to show a dialog when time exceeds 10sec but nothing happens when time exceeds 10s.

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,  10000);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Failed to fetch data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: keep the dialog cancelable(true), implement OnCancelListener for the dialog, when canceled, call finish(); to stop the activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog receives focus as soon as it's opened. You can take the user to the previous activity by calling finish() in the dialog's onCancel() callback :

```
dialog.setCancelable(true):
dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {         
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        //logic for back key goes here
         finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: I also cancelled the async task in the onCancel method.Thanks